# Get the Date from three cells (year, month and day) on spreadsheet by using google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to do the function below:

1. Input the year, month and day into three corresponding cells on the   `spreadsheet.(say A1, B1, C1 = 2016, 7, 28)`
2. Generate the events on that day on the spreadsheet

I know that the `Date` format of google script is `Date('July 20, 2015 20:00:00 UTC')`. However, could I get the date without converting the month to string?

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

```
var date = new Date(2016, 7, 29);
```

## Explanation

From: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview

> [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do new and cool things with Google Apps like Docs, Sheets, and Forms.

So to create a Date object on Google Apps Script it's possible to use any of the valid syntaxes to call Date as a constructor.

## References

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date